# Angular controller module fails to instantiate after Grunt uglify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have been trouble-shooting my heroku build and have been unable to pin down the reason as to why this angular module is not instantiating.  When I run my app on localhost everything runs fine, so I assume that the error takes place during Grunt’s uglification process.  All of my similar controller modules seem to load fine and I can see them in the “Sources” tab in dev tools.  However this controller file does not show up, I assume because there is some error inside of it.

Here is the module (controller) that doesn’t instantiate:

```
angular.module('inspector.location', [])
.controller('LocationDisplayController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams,
 ResultService) {
  var controller = this;
  this.inspections = ResultService.inspections;
});
```

What it looks like uglified (I set mangle to false in an attempt to fix this issue):
    angular.module("inspector.location",
      []).controller("LocationDisplayController",function($scope,$http,$routeParams,Resu    ltService){this.inspections=ResultService.inspections})

This is it’s only non-built-in dependency:

```
.service('ResultService', function(){
  this.value = '';
  this.inspections = '';
})
```

Here is app.js:

```
angular.module('inspector', [
  'inspector.search',
  'inspector.results',
  'inspector.location',
  'inspector.services',
  'ngRoute'
])
```

and here is the full error:

```
angular.js:4630 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
module inspector due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module inspector.location
due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'inspector.location' is not available! You
either
misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module 
ensure 
that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/nomod?p0=inspector.location
at https://ancient-sea-93514.herokuapp.com/scripts/angular/angular.js:68:12
. . . .
```

**Edit for changes made.
New version of LocationDisplayController:

```
angular.module('inspector.location', [])
.controller('LocationDisplayController', ['ResultService',
function(ResultService) {
  var controller = this;
  controller.inspections = ResultService.inspections;
}]);

LocationDisplayController.$inject = ['ResultService']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the dependencies using the array syntax like:

```js
angular.module('inspector.location', [])
  .controller('LocationDisplayController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
  'ResultService',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, ResultService) {
      var controller = this;
      this.inspections = ResultService.inspections;
    }
  ]);
```

or explicitly using the injector so that angular knows what to inject after minification.

Comment: or use ng-annotate and let grunt add the dependency injection array

Comment: The module is still failing to instantiate after making these changes ( I tried them independently but posted them together here).  However the file for the controller shows up in my 'Sources' tab of Chrome dev Tools now, but it contains the html for my index.html instead of the javascript code for the controller.  Also I took out the dependencies I that the controller wasn't using.

Comment: Had to sort out a typo, that apparently Chrome didn't care about when I ran the app on localhost, before I could even deal with the dependency issue.  Thanks! I went with the $injector option.